# Ruby - How to get assotiative hash value in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new in ruby. Now I am doing one small project. But I am unable to getting user data from hash values. Here is my coding -

```
@user = {'name'=>"Chinmay", "email"=>"chixxx@gmail.com", "phone"=>"1234567890", "age"=>30}
```

Above array I have tried to get each in `erb` file.

Here is code -

```
Name : <%= @user.name %>
Email: <%= @user.email %>
Phone: <%= @user.phone %>
Age: <%= @user.age %> Years
```

Here I am getting error message :

```
undefined method `name' for #<Hash:0x5e040d0>
```

Please help me. Let me know how to get hash value without using any loop?

Again I was trying `@user[:name]` that one also not working. blank message coming.

Thank you for answering.

Comment: Thank you for answering. You have solved this. But I was thinking different.

Comment: This is a hash not an array as you can see from error message too.

Comment: @zauzaj Yes this is hash not an array. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing, your `@user` is not an array, it's a [hash](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html)

Basically a hash is a key-value pair and in your input, `name` is a key and `Chinmay` is a value and so on!

Each named key is a symbol with which you can access the value in hash

So, `<%= @user['name'] %>` is the way you use if you want to access the name from your hash.

This will do your job!

```
Name : <%= @user['name'] %>
Email: <%= @user['email'] %>
Phone: <%= @user['phone'] %>
Age:   <%= @user['age'] %> Years
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
Name : <%= @user.name %>
Email: <%= @user.email %>
Phone: <%= @user.phone %>
Age: <%= @user.age %> Years
```

Do it like:

```
Name : <%= @user['name'] %>
Email: <%= @user["email"] %>
Phone: <%= @user["phone"] %>
Age: <%= @user["age"] %> Years
```

Answer (score 2):

`@user` is a Hash, you should be accessing `values` by `keys` as follows:

```
Name : <%= @user['name'] %>
Email: <%= @user['email'] %>
Phone: <%= @user['phone'] %>
Age: <%= @user['age'] %> Years
```

Answer (score 2):

The right syntax to access a hash is:

```
@user['name']
@user['email']
# [...]
```

Answer (score 2):

User is a hash, not an array.

In Ruby you are accessing to hash properties like

```
@user['property']
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

First of of, what you call "associative array" is a Hash (see documentation [here](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html)) and you may access its elements by using each key as an array index.

In other words, you should write:

```
Name : <%= @user['name'] %>
Email: <%= @user['email'] %>
Phone: <%= @user['phone'] %>
Age: <%= @user['age'] %> Years
```

Answer (score 1):

*Sidenote solution*: the other way round would be to use brilliant [`Hashie::Mash`](https://github.com/intridea/hashie#mash):

somewhere in controller:

```
require 'hashie/mash'
@huser = Hashie::Mash.new @user

Name : <%= @huser.name %>
Email: <%= @huser.email %>
Phone: <%= @huser.phone %>
Age: <%= @huser.age %> Years
```

Here is seems to be an overkill, but sometimes it really helps.

Comment: cannot load such file -- hashie/mash

Comment: The gem should be added to `Gemfile`, `bundle` should be re-run.

Answer (score 1):

```
<% @yourhash.map  do |k, v|  %>
    <%=  k.capitalize %>:
    <%= p v %><br>
    <% end %>
```

solution with loop